# BigQuery: join a firestore collection with its subcollection

Tags: sql, join, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I imported my data from firestore and I have a collection `users` with a subcollection `profiles`. The key of the users can be found in `matchingUsers.__key__.name` (e.g. "USER_KEY"),  while the `__key__.path` property of the profiles subcollection is equivalent to `'"users", "USER_KEY", "profiles", "PROFILE_KEY"'`.

I'm trying to get all the users with their profile, so I'm doing a join between the two tables. For the example, I substituted `matchingUsers.__key__.name` with `userId` and `profiles.__key__.path` with `path`:

```
WITH users AS (
  SELECT "micheleId" AS userId, "Michele" as name UNION ALL
  SELECT "matteoId", "Matteo"
),
profiles AS (
    SELECT "x" AS profileId, '"users", "micheleId", "profiles", "x"' AS path, 'player' AS type UNION ALL
  SELECT "y", '"users", "micheleId", "profiles", "y"', 'coach' UNION ALL
  SELECT "z", '"users", "matteoId", "profiles", "z"', 'team'
)
SELECT userId, profileId, type 
FROM users JOIN profiles ON users.userId IN UNNEST(SPLIT(profiles.path ));
```

I `SPLIT` the path to get an array and then using `IN UNNEST` to join only if the user key is in the path.

I'm getting an empty result out of this, while I would expect exactly:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| userId    | profileId | type   |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| micheleId | x         | player |
| micheleId | y         | coach  |
| matteoId  | z         | team   |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: your query looks like either made up (assuming it will help us) or oversimplification of what you really have - so it is really hard to help you here. see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant and Gordon I added a reproducible example and the expected result. Now should be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a way to "fix" your query (change is only in the last line)

```
#standardSQL
WITH users AS (
  SELECT "micheleId" AS userId, "Michele" AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT "matteoId", "Matteo"
),
profiles AS (
  SELECT "x" AS profileId, 'users, micheleId, profiles, x' AS path, 'player' AS type UNION ALL
  SELECT "y", 'users, micheleId, profiles, y', 'coach' UNION ALL
  SELECT "z", 'users, matteoId, profiles, z', 'team'
)
SELECT userId, profileId, type 
FROM users 
JOIN profiles 
ON users.userId IN UNNEST(SPLIT(REPLACE(profiles.path, ' ', '')))
```

Depends on your real use case - there can be a variations of above like below

```
ON users.userId IN UNNEST(SPLIT(profiles.path, ', '))
```

OR

```
ON users.userId IN UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(profiles.path, r'\s', '')))
```

... and so on

In all above cases - result is

```
Row userId      profileId   type     
1   micheleId   x           player   
2   micheleId   y           coach    
3   matteoId    z           team
```

> My bad, I wrongly added the path string. The correct format is '"users", "micheleId", "profiles", "x"' as updated in the question

Below is "fix" for it too

```
#standardSQL
WITH users AS (
  SELECT "micheleId" AS userId, "Michele" AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT "matteoId", "Matteo"
),
profiles AS (
    SELECT "x" AS profileId, '"users", "micheleId", "profiles", "x"' AS path, 'player' AS type UNION ALL
  SELECT "y", '"users", "micheleId", "profiles", "y"', 'coach' UNION ALL
  SELECT "z", '"users", "matteoId", "profiles", "z"', 'team'
)
SELECT userId, profileId, type 
FROM users JOIN profiles 
ON users.userId IN UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(profiles.path, r'[" ]', '' )))
```

with, obviously, same result

```
Row userId      profileId   type     
1   micheleId   x           player   
2   micheleId   y           coach    
3   matteoId    z           team
```

as you see  - same idea of fixing

Comment: My bad, I wrongly added the path string. The correct format is '"users", "micheleId", "profiles", "x"' as updated in the question. Can you please check it out this format?